# Issue with the BitcoinJ for Litecoin. Which dependency can be used for Litecoin?

Tags: android, bitcoinj, litecoin

I've created a crypto-currency wallet for Bitcoin using BitcoinJ. Now I want to add Litecoin in this wallet. How to implement BitcoinJ dependency for Litecoin? 
While using BitcoinJ for both Litecoin and Bitcoin, I was getting blockchain of Bitcoin for both the addresses. What should I do so that I can get Bicoin blockchain for Bitcoin address and Litecoin blockchain for Litecoin address?

here is dependency which is I used>>>

```
  implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
```

here is my code for bitcoin blockchain download initialisation>>>

```
  public void initWallet() {
    ECKey key;
    String btcpri = 
     "cxxxxxre75ENAnpGjUr8EEdP2kxtvk1r65nTydnM954n4WxxxxxM";
    if (btcpri.length() == 51 || btcpri.length() == 52) {
        DumpedPrivateKey dumpedPrivateKey = 
        DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(params, btcpri);
        key = dumpedPrivateKey.getKey();
    } else {
        BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(btcpri);
        key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privKey);
    }
    Log.e("key ", String.valueOf(key));
    setBtcSDKThread();
    BriefLogFormatter.init();

    kit = new WalletAppKit(params, file, "btc_justbitcoin") {
        @Override
        protected void onSetupCompleted() {
            wallet().importKey(key);
            setupWalletListeners(wallet());
            Log.e("Address ", 
            String.valueOf(wallet().freshReceiveAddress()));
        }
    };
    kit.setBlockingStartup(false);
    kit.startAsync();
    kit.awaitRunning();
 }
```

Comment: no one have answer of this question?

Comment: You need to overwrite the Network parameters for Litecoin